# Cell fracture producing warped faces

Tags: mesh, grease-pencil

I have a plane that I have been trying to fracture (similar to the way glass can break).  I used the grease pencil and solidify modifier with the default settings.

For some reason, when I use cell fracture it causes the faces of the shards to have convex surfaces rather than flat like the plane had.  How do I get them to look flat?  I tried using the debug boolean option which produced the look I want, but the shards seemed to disappear into thin air when I apply active physics to them.

**Here's the pic of my results:**

[image]

**These are my settings:**

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Here is the .blend:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try out the Fracture Modifier Build.

Make sure to use the "latest development build", or just use the more recent graphicall build.

I also had to edit 3 points or so of the greasepencil strokes, because the FM (fracture modifier) created some holes in the mesh there (points were too close to each other)

For the simulation I made the bullet a trigger and the plane animated and triggered. Furthermore I played a bit around with constraints.

If you have further questions, please post either here on stackexchange or here :

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?343637-Custom-Build-Blender-Fracture-Modifier

[image]

Comment: I wasn't able to install the add-on for some reason.  I see though that it comes built in to one of the latest versions of blender from your links.  I'll have to try that.

Comment: well, technically it is a standalone build of blender. It involved lots of changes in the C source code. there is an optional addon bundled with this build, but only to automate things a bit within this build, regarding to FM.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the problem was that the solidify modifier was too thin for the plane.  By increasing it slightly, cell fracture produced the desired normal flat faces.